# How to store SPAN values from JSON to html form using PHP post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I've been working on a form where I'm retrieving the city/state information using JSON file. I've reached to a stage where I can see the related city/state, when the user enters their PIN code. Now the bit that i'm stuck on is, on parsing this information to the database when the user submits the form.

The information on city/state is getting populated in the  field on the form, immediately after filling in the PIN code but I'm not able to get this data entered into the database, despite trying multiple option (hidden field, trying to store in a variable).

So far, the form gets filled in easily and is taking all the information, except for the details getting populated in the  field.

My form is as follows;

```
    <?php
include("inc/dbconnect.php");

session_start();
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
if($username=="")
{
    header("location:index.php");
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Add new lead</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<style>
  .ui-autocomplete-loading {
    background: white url("img/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif") right center no-repeat;
  }
   .ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  /* IE 6 doesn't support max-height
   * we use height instead, but this forces the menu to always be this tall
   */
  * html .ui-autocomplete {
    height: 100px;
  }
  </style>

<script src="inc/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="inc/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(
function () {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
changeMonth: true,//this option for allowing user to select month
changeYear: true //this option for allowing user to select from year range
});
}
);
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(
function () {
$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
changeMonth: true,//this option for allowing user to select month
changeYear: true //this option for allowing user to select from year range
});
}
);
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(
function () {
$( "#datepicker3" ).datepicker({
changeMonth: true,//this option for allowing user to select month
changeYear: true //this option for allowing user to select from year range
});
}
);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="900px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
      <td height="30"><?php include("inc/header2.php")?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding:30px;"><form action="addlead.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" id="form">
      <table width="660" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="resultborder">
        <tr>
          <td width="684" colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle" class="resultheading2">Add  new lead</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle" style="padding-top:5px;"><?php if(isset($msg)) {echo $msg;}?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle" style="padding-top:5px;"><table width="660" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">Lead source</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><select name="source" id="source" style="width:308px; height:30px; padding:2px; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px;" required>
                  <option value="">Select lead source</option>
                    <option value="Sales ID">Sales ID</option>
                    <option value="Call back">Call Back</option>
                    <option value="Toll Free">Toll Free</option>
                    <option value="Walk-in">Walk-in</option>
                    <option value="Referral">Referral</option>
                    <option value="Exhibition">Exhibition Data</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">CEP reference (if any)</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><select name="cep_ref" id="cep_ref" style="width:308px; height:30px; padding:2px; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px;" >
                  <option value="-">Select CEP reference</option>
                  <option value="NA">Not Applicable</option>
                  <option value="Pallavi">Pallavi</option>
                  <option value="Pooja">Pooja</option>
                  <option value="Rashmi">Rashmi</option>
                  <option value="Savita">Savita</option>
                  <option value="Shaily">Shaily</option>
                </select>              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td width="209" align="left" class="fieldhome">Lead date</td>
              <td width="416" align="left" valign="middle"><input id="datepicker" name="inq_date" required="required" class="addformtextfield" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">Call date</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><input id="datepicker2" name="call_date" class="addformtextfield" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">Company Name</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><input type="text" name="company" id="company" class="addformtextfield" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">Customers Name</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="required" class="addformtextfield" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">Mobile number</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" required="required" class="addformtextfield" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">Landline number</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" required="required" class="addformtextfield" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">Email</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" required="required" class="addformtextfield" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">Designation</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><input type="text" name="designation" id="designation" class="addformtextfield" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">Nature of Industry</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><select name="nature_ind" id="nature_ind" style="width:308px; height:30px; padding:2px; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px;" >
                  <option value="-">Select Nature of Industry</option>
                  <option value="Trader">Trader</option>
                  <option value="Manufacturer">Manufacturer</option>
                  <option value="Individual">Individual</option>
              </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">Address</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="addformtextfield" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">Pin Code</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle">
              <div>
              <input type="text" id="pin" name="pin" placeholder="Enter pincode" width="40%"><span style="color:red; font-size:9px;"> Enter at least 3 digit to show auto-complete.</span></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
   $( "#pin" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "pincodes.php",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            q: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
            response( data );
          }
        });
      },
      minLength: 3,  // Set minum input length
      select: function( event, ui ) {
            //do something on select event
            var vl = ui.item.id;      
            var data = vl.split("-");
            console.log(data);
            $("#city").html(data[2]);
            $("#taluka").html(data[3]);
            $("#state").html(data[4]);
        //console.log(ui.item); // ui.item is  responded json from server
      },
      open: function() {
                 // D0 something on open event.
      },
      close: function() {
               // Do omething on close event
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">Taluka:</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="taluka"></span> <?php $taluka='<span id="taluka"></span>'?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">City:</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="city"></span>    <input type="hidden" name="city" id="city" value="" />
</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">State:</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><span id="state" name="state"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">Potential</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><select name="potential" id="potential" style="width:308px; height:30px; padding:2px; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px;" >
                  <option value="-">Select lead potential</option>
                  <option value="High">High</option>
                  <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                  <option value="Low">Low</option>
              </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">Purchases what all?</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><textarea rows="2" cols="32" name="what_purchases" style="padding:2px; font-family:Arial; font-size:18px;"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">Other important contacts</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><textarea rows="2" cols="32" name="other_contacts" style="padding:2px; font-family:Arial; font-size:18px;"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">Turn over</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><select name="turnover" id="turnover" style="width:308px; height:30px; padding:2px; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px;" >
                  <option value="-">Select Customer's Turnover</option>
                  <option value="Less than 50L">Less than 50L</option>
                  <option value="1Cr to 2Cr">1Cr - 2Cr</option>
                  <option value="2Cr to 5Cr">2Cr-5Cr</option>
                  <option value="5Cr to 10Cr">5Cr-10Cr</option>
                  <option value="10Cr plus">10Cr+</option>
              </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">Total Employees</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><select name="employees" id="employees" style="width:308px; height:30px; padding:2px; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px;" >
                  <option value="-">Total number of employees</option>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2 to 5">2-5</option>
                  <option value="5 to 10">5-10</option>
                  <option value="10 to 100">10-100</option>
                  <option value="100 to 500">100-500</option>
                  <option value="500 plus">500+</option>
              </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">New customer?</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><select name="new_cust" id="new_cust" style="width:308px; height:30px; padding:2px; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px;" required>
                  <option value="">Please choose if a new lead?</option>
                  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                  <option value="Existing-lat">Existing-LAT</option>
                  <option value="Existing-other">Existing-Other</option>
              </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">Follow up date</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><input id="datepicker3" name="follow_up" class="addformtextfield" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">Lead Status</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><select name="lead_status" id="lead_status" style="width:308px; height:30px; padding:2px; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px;" >
                  <option value="-">Select lead status</option>
                  <option value="Won-online">Won-online</option>
                  <option value="Won-offline">Won-offline</option>
                  <option value="Lost">Lost</option>
                  <option value="Regret">Regret</option>
                  <option value="Disqualified">Disqualified</option>
                  <option value="Not reachable">Not reachable</option>
                  <option value="Hold">Hold</option>
              </select></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td align="left" class="fieldhome">Remarks</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><textarea rows="8" cols="32" name="remarks" style="padding:2px; font-family:Arial; font-size:18px;"></textarea></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td align="center" class="fieldhome">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="width:80px; font-size:18px; padding:8px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial; color:#333333;" /></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php include "inc/footer.php"?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One question, i see the success function (data) , it is asyncronous call, i can't see the response(data) function in your code. My question are you reciving correctly the data result when you console.log it into select: function ?

Comment: @JordiJordi could you please elaborate that a bit more? I'm not sure what that mean (may be due to my limited knowledge). thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be with "multipart/form-data". Try to use "urlencoded" instead of "multipart/form-data" (remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from your form).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm right but i think that when you do

```
$("#city").html(data[2]);
   $("#taluka").html(data[3]);
   $("#state").html(data[4]);
```

you are actually changing the HTML itself with `data[]` and not the value of the

```
<input type="hidden" name="city" id="city" value="" />
```

Comment: @valen-dsouza not sure what that means. Do you suggest a better way to get that data? Please excuse my limited knowledge.